# how to add more padding to table rows when table has array inside it?

Tags: tables, spacing

The solutions I found to add more spacing between table rows is to use `\arraystretch`

But this is not working for me. The table I have has `\begin{array}` inside it. And the `\arraystretch` is stretching the array inside the table and not the adding more space between the bottom of the vectors shown and the table rows, which is all I wanted.

**Please note**: I can't change the code that uses `array` to typeset the vector in the last column, to something else. As that code is autogenerated.

I can change anything else in the table, but have to keep the `array` code as is. I have no way to change that.

And example will help explain.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\bgroup
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
eigenvalue & {\footnotesize algebraic multiplicity $m$}&  {\footnotesize geometric multiplicty $k$}& {\small defective?}& eigenvectors \\ \hline 
$3 i$&$1$&$1$&No&$\left[\begin{array}{c}i \\1 \\\end{array}\right]$ \\ \hline
$-3 i$&$1$&$1$&No&$\left[\begin{array}{c}-i \\1 \\\end{array}\right]$ \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\egroup
\end{center}                       
\end{document}
```

When compiled using lualatex, this is the output

[image]

Changing `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}` to `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{5}` also stretches the vectors inside keeping the same space between the bottom of the vectors and the table edges which is not what I want.

Here is the result with `5`

[image]

What is the correct way to solve this? I just need more space between the top/bottom of the vectors shown and the lines that separate the rows. The rest of the cells are OK as they are.

TL 2020

reference:

[overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/How_do_I_change_column_or_row_separation_in_LaTeX_tables%3F#:%7E:text=One%20option%20is%20to%20use,spacing%20(row%20separation)%20respectively.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add some vertical space to cells contents by use of the macro  `\makegapedcells` defined in the `makecell` packages. Since you table is to wide that can be fit into text width, I suggest to reformulate column headers for the second and the third column:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \setcellgapes{5pt}
    \makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{|*{5}{c|} }
    \hline
    &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ multiplicity}
            &   &                   \\
    \cline{2-3}
eigenvalue 
    &   algebraic $m$
        &   multiplicty $k$
            &   defective?
                &   eigenvectors    \\ 
    \hline
$3i$    & 1 & 1 &   No  & $\begin{bmatrix} i \\1 \end{bmatrix}$     \\ 
    \hline
$-3i$   & 1 & 1 &   No  & $\begin{bmatrix} -i \\1 \end{bmatrix}$     \\ 
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**

If you for some reason use your code for matrices, than just replace short and elegant code using `bmatrix` with your code using `array`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \setcellgapes{5pt}
    \makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{|*{5}{c|} }
    \hline
    &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ multiplicity}
            &   &                   \\
    \cline{2-3}
eigenvalue 
    &   algebraic $m$
        &   multiplicty $k$
            &   defective?
                &   eigenvectors    \\ 
    \hline
$3i$    & 1 & 1 &   No  & $\left[\begin{array}{c} i \\1 \end{array}\right]$     \\ 
    \hline
$-3i$   & 1 & 1 &   No  & $\left[\begin{array}{c} -i \\1 \end{array}\right]$     \\ 
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

The result of above solution is the same as before ...

Comment: Thanks. I am sorry, but I can't change the code I have which uses array for the vectors to using bmatrix. the code is auto-generated which uses array for vectors.  I can change the table itself and add anything around it. But not the code for the vectors. I'll mention this in my question.

Comment: @Nasser, `bmatrix` is defined in the `amsmath` package ... why you not allowed all what it offer? Anyway, you can instead of it use your code for matrices (using `array`). Result will stay the same ...

Comment: I'll try your code and see if it works with array for vectors. The code generated for the vectors is generated by external program and I just copied it over. I can't tell the other program to use bmatrix or something else.  If your code works with array, that will be great. Will try it soon...

Comment: @Nasser, see edited answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your code does exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

The `cellspace` package enables you to define a *minimal* vertical padding at the top and bottom of cells in columns with specifier prefixed with the letter `S` (or `C` if you load `siunitx`, and the `math` option does the same for the `amsmath`  matrix environments.
Independently from this problem, I took the liberty to simplify your code by replacing `\left[\begin{array}[c}...\end{array}\right]` with the simpler `\begin{bmatrix} ... \end{bmatrix}`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[math]{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{6pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{6pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|*{5}{Sc|}}\hline
eigenvalue & {\footnotesize algebraic multiplicity $m$}& {\footnotesize geometric multiplicty $k$}& {\small defective?}& eigenvectors \\ \hline
$3 i$&$1$&$1$&No&$\begin{bmatrix}i \\ \,1\, \end{bmatrix}$ \\ \hline
$-3 i$&$1$&$1$&No&$\begin{bmatrix} -i \\1 \\\end{bmatrix}$ \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]