# error when using 'm' option in tabular after adding command \makegapedcells

Tags: tables, arrays, makecell

I added the command `\makegapedcells` from package `makecell` and now my tabular gives error when using `m` for fields.

There seems to be some conflict. Here is MW.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell} %make sure before arydshln
%see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/563115/how-to-add-more-padding-to-table-rows-when-table-has-array-inside-it
\setcellgapes{5pt} %added march 14,2021
\makegapedcells  %added march 14,2021 
  
\begin{document}  
\begin{tabular}[c]{|m{2in}|m{4in}|}\hline
cell 1
&
cell 2
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Now, `lualatex foo5.tex` gives

```
(base) >lualatex foo5.tex
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.12.0 (TeX Live 2020)
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./foo5.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 2


 L3 programming layer <2020-12-07> xparse <2020-03-03> (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls
Document Class: book 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/bk12.clo)) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/makecell/makecell.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-luatex.def) (./foo5.aux) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
$
l.11 c
    ell 1
?
```

If I change `m` in the table to `p`, the error goes away. Also, if I remove the command `\makegapedcells`, the error goes away.

Why does this happen? Is this a bug? or Am I not using it correctly?

I am using `\makegapedcells` to get more space between rows as documented in the package `makecell`

[image]

I know as a workaround, I could do the following

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell} %make sure before arydshln
\setcellgapes{5pt} %added march 14,2021

\begin{document}  
\begin{tabular}[c]{|m{2in}|m{4in}|}\hline
\makegapedcells
cell 1
&
cell 2
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

And now it compiles. But I have 100's of tables in many files, and I do not want to search for each and change it like the above. so that is why I used `\makegapedcells` in the preamble.

reference:

https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/makecell/makecell.pdf

**edit 4/13/2021**

The patch posted in answer below does not work. I still get same error

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{makecell}
\setcellgapes{5pt} 
\makegapedcells  %I need to add this to make cell spacing larger. 

%%FROM https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319768/are-m-column-type-and-makecell-incompatible   
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\mcell@classz{\@classx
    \@tempcnta \count@
    \prepnext@tok
    \@addtopreamble{%\mcell@mstyle
        \ifcase\@chnum
        \hfil
        \mcell@agape{\d@llarbegin\insert@column\d@llarend}\hfil \or
        \hskip1sp
        \mcell@agape{\d@llarbegin\insert@column\d@llarend}\hfil \or
        \hfil\hskip1sp
        \mcell@agape{\d@llarbegin \insert@column\d@llarend}\or
        \mcell@agape{$\vcenter
            \@startpbox{\@nextchar}\insert@column\@endpbox$}\or
        \mcell@agape{\vtop
            \@startpbox{\@nextchar}\insert@column\@endpbox}\or
        \mcell@agape{\vbox
            \@startpbox{\@nextchar}\insert@column\@endpbox}%
        \fi
        \global\let\mcell@left\relax\global\let\mcell@right\relax
    }\prepnext@tok}

\makeatletter

 
\begin{document}  

\begin{tabular}[c]{|m{2in}|m{4in}|}\hline
cell 1
&
cell 2
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

gives

```
lualatex foo5.tex
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.12.0 (TeX Live 2020)
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./foo5.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 2


 L3 programming layer <2020-12-07> xparse <2020-03-03> (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo)) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/makecell/makecell.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-luatex.def) (./foo5.aux) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
$
l.37 c
    ell 1
?
```

Also, `arraystretch` does not really work.  I need to have extra space added in the cell. Here is an example showing it does not work

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{3}% does not work
 
\begin{document}  

\begin{center}%
\begin{tabular}[c]{|l|l|l|}\hline
Spin matrix & Eigenvalues & Eigenvectors\\\hline
$S_{x}=\frac{\hbar}{2}%
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$ & $\frac{\hbar}{2},-\frac{\hbar}{2}$ & $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}%
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
1
\end{bmatrix}
\qquad\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}%
\begin{bmatrix}
-1\\
1
\end{bmatrix}
$\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Compare to when using `usepackage{makecell}`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{makecell}
\setcellgapes{5pt} 
\makegapedcells  %works as long as m is not used
 
\begin{document}  

\begin{center}%
\begin{tabular}[c]{|l|l|l|}\hline
Spin matrix & Eigenvalues & Eigenvectors\\\hline
$S_{x}=\frac{\hbar}{2}%
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$ & $\frac{\hbar}{2},-\frac{\hbar}{2}$ & $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}%
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
1
\end{bmatrix}
\qquad\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}%
\begin{bmatrix}
-1\\
1
\end{bmatrix}
$\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

The above is what I want. But I wanted it to work with the `m` option.  So I am afraid answer below does not solve this problem. The patch still gives an error when using `m` option.

**Edit 4/13/2021**

After more experiments, `\makegapedcells` can be used in preamble, but has to be AFTER the patch. As follows

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{makecell}
\setcellgapes{5pt} 
%%FROM https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319768/are-m-column-type-and-makecell-incompatible   
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\mcell@classz{\@classx
    \@tempcnta \count@
    \prepnext@tok
    \@addtopreamble{%\mcell@mstyle
        \ifcase\@chnum
        \hfil
        \mcell@agape{\d@llarbegin\insert@column\d@llarend}\hfil \or
        \hskip1sp
        \mcell@agape{\d@llarbegin\insert@column\d@llarend}\hfil \or
        \hfil\hskip1sp
        \mcell@agape{\d@llarbegin \insert@column\d@llarend}\or
        \mcell@agape{$\vcenter
            \@startpbox{\@nextchar}\insert@column\@endpbox$}\or
        \mcell@agape{\vtop
            \@startpbox{\@nextchar}\insert@column\@endpbox}\or
        \mcell@agape{\vbox
            \@startpbox{\@nextchar}\insert@column\@endpbox}%
        \fi
        \global\let\mcell@left\relax\global\let\mcell@right\relax
    }\prepnext@tok}

\makeatletter

\makegapedcells % HAS to be AFTER the batch, else compiler error

\begin{document}  

\begin{tabular}[c]{|m{2in}|m{4in}|}\hline
    cell 1  &       cell 2\\    \hline
    cell 3  &       cell 4\\    \hline      
    cell 5  &       cell 6\\    \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Now compiles OK

```
lualatex foo5.tex
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.12.0 (TeX Live 2020)
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./foo5.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 2
    
 L3 programming layer <2020-12-07> xparse <2020-03-03> (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo)) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/makecell/makecell.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-luatex.def) (./foo5.aux) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
Overfull \hbox (86.81996pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 35--40
[][]
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./foo5.aux))
(see the transcript file for additional information)
 484 words of node memory still in use:
   6 hlist, 2 vlist, 2 rule, 2 glue, 4 kern, 1 glyph, 6 attribute, 52 glue_spec, 6 attribute_list, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 2:91,3:28,4:1,5:21,6:14,7:210,8:1,9:164
</usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman12-regular.otf>
Output written on foo5.pdf (1 page, 3677 bytes).
Transcript written on foo5.log.
```

Now I can use `m` type and also use `\makegapedcells` in preamble. I wanted to use this in preamble only for other reasons.

Comment: The answer posted works fine. You should use the command `\makegapedcells` after `\begin{document}` not in the preamble

Comment: The braces will follow the height of the inner `bmatrix` so naturally `\arraystretch` will not produce the desired result.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/319775/161015 for a patch and  put `\makegapedcells` inside  the environment  instead of the preamble.

Try the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
    
\usepackage{array}  
\usepackage{makecell} %make sure before arydshln    

%%FROM https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319768/are-m-column-type-and-makecell-incompatible   
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\mcell@classz{\@classx
    \@tempcnta \count@
    \prepnext@tok
    \@addtopreamble{%\mcell@mstyle
        \ifcase\@chnum
        \hfil
        \mcell@agape{\d@llarbegin\insert@column\d@llarend}\hfil \or
        \hskip1sp
        \mcell@agape{\d@llarbegin\insert@column\d@llarend}\hfil \or
        \hfil\hskip1sp
        \mcell@agape{\d@llarbegin \insert@column\d@llarend}\or
        \mcell@agape{$\vcenter
            \@startpbox{\@nextchar}\insert@column\@endpbox$}\or
        \mcell@agape{\vtop
            \@startpbox{\@nextchar}\insert@column\@endpbox}\or
        \mcell@agape{\vbox
            \@startpbox{\@nextchar}\insert@column\@endpbox}%
        \fi
        \global\let\mcell@left\relax\global\let\mcell@right\relax
    }\prepnext@tok}

\makeatletter
%% *************************************************************************
\begin{document}  
\setcellgapes{5pt} %added march 14,2021
\makegapedcells % put it here <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{tabular}[c]{|m{2in}|m{4in}|}\hline
    cell 1  &       cell 2\\    \hline
    cell 3  &       cell 4\\    \hline      
    cell 5  &       cell 6\\    \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: b]

Comment: Thanks. But after testing it more, the patch does not work. I still get same error as before.  In your posted example, you did not include `\makegapedcells` and that is why you did not see the compile error. Also, `\arraystretch` does not really work. I'll post an example showing this.

Comment: @Nasser Please note that  `\makegapedcells`  IS included, albeit after `\begin{document}` not in the preamble.

Comment: FYI, it works in preamble, but needed to add `\makegapedcells` after patch code, n ot before it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend `nicematrix` with its key `cell-space-limits` which is compatible with the columns of type `m`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-limits=5pt}

\begin{document}  

\begin{center}%
\begin{NiceTabular}[c]{lll}[hvlines]
Spin matrix & Eigenvalues & Eigenvectors\\
$S_{x}=\frac{\hbar}{2}%
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$ & $\frac{\hbar}{2},-\frac{\hbar}{2}$ & $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}%
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
1
\end{bmatrix}
\qquad\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}%
\begin{bmatrix}
-1\\
1
\end{bmatrix}
$\\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{center}


\begin{center}
\begin{NiceTabular}[c]{>{\raggedright}m{4cm}ll}[hvlines]
Spin matrix & Eigenvalues & Eigenvectors\\
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
& $\frac{\hbar}{2},-\frac{\hbar}{2}$ & $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}%
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
1
\end{bmatrix}
\qquad\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}%
\begin{bmatrix}
-1\\
1
\end{bmatrix}
$\\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]